# show that if $G$ is a $2$-connected graph containing a vertex that is adjacent to at least three vertices of degree $2$, then $G$ is not Hamiltonian.

Tags: graph-theory, proof-writing, hamiltonian-path

I would like to see how to show this statement is true. Can someone demonstrate why this is not Hamiltonian?

Comment: What is your question? Are you asking whether your proof is correct?

Comment: You said: "Now assume, to the contrary, that $G$ is Hamiltonian. Then $\deg v\ge n/2$ for every $v$ contained within $V(G).$" How does that follow? What about $G=C_6$? It is Hamiltonian, but it's not true that every vertex has degree $\ge6/2.$

Comment: Yes, you are right, thank you. I just doubled checked it and realized I was treating the theorem like an if and only if statement. My question is how to show the graph is not Hamiltonian under the given condtions but I put my first attempt up as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the obstruction to having a Hamilton cycle:

[image]

(The rest of the graph is not shown, but there are no additional edges with a red vertex as an endpoint.)

If the graph has a Hamilton cycle, then it does not use all three edges $xa$, $xb$, and $xc$ (or else it's not a cycle).  Thus, we can delete the edge not used in the Hamilton cycle, and we still have a Hamiltonian graph.

However, after deleting any one of these three edges, one of the vertices $a$, $b$, or $c$ becomes a degree-$1$ vertex.  This contradicts the graph being Hamiltonian (since all vertices in a Hamilton cycle have degree $2>1$).

Comment: Why is the unused edge deleted? I see how there's a contradiction when it is removed however, I am not sure why it was deleted could you further elaborate?

Comment: It's deleted to create a degree-1 vertex in a graph that should be Hamiltonian, thereby getting a contradiction.  (There's going to be ways to make the argument without deleting it, but this one seemed the simplest.)